# UWP page transitions applied to frame for all pages

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I currently have a UWP page which acts as my main window and defines the common menu/header wrapper that goes around everything else.

I then have a `<frame/>`

```
<Frame Name="ContentFrame" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I have about 10 pages that i `Navigate()` to using the content frame, but i would like to add the UWP page transitions, but not be forced to add the transition to every single page (it feels messy, and i dont want to forget when i add new pages).

Is there a way to define the transition within the frame its self so that all child pages will transition?

I have tried this, but with no luck

```
<Frame Name="ContentFrame" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <SlideNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the answer by accident (intelisence):

I was missing the `Frame.ContentTransitions` tags to make the animation apply to the child pages.

```
<Frame Name="ContentFrame" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition>
                <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                    <SlideNavigationTransitionInfo/>
                </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
            </NavigationThemeTransition>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Frame.ContentTransitions>
</Frame>
```